# Django-registration how to check if user exists

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views, django-registration

I'm using [Django-registration](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.2/index.html) with Django 1.8.15 to register users. My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
from registration.backends.hmac.views import RegistrationView

url(r'^registration/register/$', RegistrationView.as_view(form_class=MyCustomSubscriberForm), name="registration_register"),
```

This is basically a CBV where I provide the form and the template.
Here's the form:

```
class MyCustomSubscriberForm(RegistrationForm):

class Meta:
    model = MyCustomSubscriber
    fields = ('firstname', 'surname', 'email', )
```

**My problem is how to handle validation in this CBV?**

At the moment if e.g. somebody tries to register with an already used email address Django gives a `IntegrityError at /registration/register/` ...

What is the best way to use [Validators from Django-registrations](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.2/validators.html#validation-utilities)? For instance - how do I make sure that if a user with a certain e-mail already exists the users gets notified in the template?

**How to extend this CBV or handle this error in my code with those validators already provided by Django-Registration?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into Django-registration more carefully I discovered that Django-registration already has this functionality implemented in one of its forms: `RegistrationFormUniqueEmail` which is a subclass of `RegistrationForm`.

To make use of it I just had to subclass it in my form like this:

```
class MyCustomSubscriberForm(RegistrationFormUniqueEmail):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super (RegistrationFormUniqueEmail, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

   class Meta: 
      model = get_user_model()
      fields = ('firstname', 'lastname', 'email')
```

And that was it - the form was checking the if the provided email address is unique.

Answer (score 3):

You need to validate the emails in your form's `clean_<field>` method and raise and error if it's a duplicate e-mail which you'll be able to render in your template.

Please take a look at this section from the documentation: [Cleaning a specific field attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

So you can have something like the code below:

```
def clean_email(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data['email']
    duplicate_users = User.objects.filter(email=data)
    if self.instance.pk is not None:  # If you're editing an user, remove him from the duplicated results
        duplicate_users = duplicate_users.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
    if duplicate_users.exists():
        raise forms.ValidationError("E-mail is already registered!")
    return data
```

Comment: you need to handle edit mode ;)
```qs = User.objects.filter(email=data)
if self.instance.id:
    qs = qs.exclude(id=id)```

Comment: You're absolutely correct, I've edited my answer. But since he has a registration form he might not use it for editing.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, this is certainly possible! Certainly this is a valid answer, however there's also then possibility to use the in-built Django-Registration feature which does exactly this - as described in my answer.